# What is the best type of model to use to predict integers?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, modeling

I am trying to develop a simple model in R which will predict the number of shots a player will take to complete a hole in golf, given the par and the distance of the hole.

I generated some random Gaussian data, which is what I am working with, but I'll want it to work given the input from an actual player. I'm just struggling with model selection. I don't think I can use a regression model since the output will always be an integer. So I tried a Naive Bayes Classifier, however the output from the prediction is always the integer with the highest prior probability. In this case the distance is the only predictor.

Therefore, I wonder if there is not a better model I can use for this sort of problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regression model where the par and the distance are both covariates. You're right that a regular linear regression model wouldn't work, since our response of interest is an integer, but check out generalized linear models (see `glm` in R). These allow for responses to be other data types. In your case, you could investigate Poisson regression, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! I will try a Poisson regression, did not think to use that. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!